# Combinatorics Pigeonhole principle series

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

Let *a*, *b* denote series with length of *2n*

such that for every *1* $\leq$ *i* $\leq$ *2n*: *1* $\leq$ $a_i$ $\leq$ n and 1 $\leq$ $b_i$ $\leq$ n

prove that there are index sets I, J $\subseteq$ [2n] such that

$$\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \sum_{j \in J} b_j$$

That question was taken from homework of combinatorics and graph theory course